# Android virtual KeyBord and Edit Text

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my virtual keyboard, it hides the text boxes in which I want to write

my xml manifest, I added code to try but nothing works (Still the keyboard hides text boxes ):

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="

http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.Pointage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.Activity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_activity2"
             >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.Bdd"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bdd" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
```

Reference [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html)

Comment: try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  instead

Comment: If that doesn't work too put your layout in scrollview . It will help

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: There is not a way to put the keyboard below the text box?

Comment: you cannot misplace the keyboard but If  you put the textbox in a scrollview it will move automically above the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```